# What is the best way to update an array with some updated and deleted results using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following array:

```
workedHours = [
  {hours: 3, id: 1234, name: 'John Doe'},
  {hours: 2, id: 5678, name: 'Steve Harris'},
  {hours: 4, id: 1928, name: 'Richard McNeil'},
  {hours: 1, id: 9876, name: 'Kirk Hammet'},
  {hours: 3, id: 5432, name: 'Lucas Moore'},
]
```

An I just receive the following response with some updatedHours and some deletedHours:

```
response = {
  updatedHours: [
    {hours: 4, id: 5678, name: 'Steve Harris'},
    {hours: 2, id: 9876, name: 'Kirk Hammet'},
  ],
  deletedHours: [
    {hours: 3, id: 5432, name: 'Lucas Moore'},
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to update the hours array, removing the deletedHours and replacing the updatedHours with the items in the respond using lodash? So I can have the following result with new hours after updating:

```
workedHours = [
  {hours: 3, id: 1234, name: 'John Doe'},
  {hours: 4, id: 5678, name: 'Steve Harris'},
  {hours: 4, id: 1928, name: 'Richard McNeil'},
  {hours: 2, id: 9876, name: 'Kirk Hammet'},
]
```

I can think on a optimized way... Can you guys help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: correction: "I **can't** think on a optimized way"

Comment: You can edit the question for any correction.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array.filter` to remove deletedHours and updatedHours from the original array, then you push back all updatedHours with `array.concat`.

```js
var workedHours = [
  {hours: 3, id: 1234, name: 'John Doe'},
  {hours: 2, id: 5678, name: 'Steve Harris'},
  {hours: 4, id: 1928, name: 'Richard McNeil'},
  {hours: 1, id: 9876, name: 'Kirk Hammet'},
  {hours: 3, id: 5432, name: 'Lucas Moore'},
];
var response = {
  updatedHours: [{hours: 4, id: 5678, name: 'Steve Harris'},{hours: 2, id: 9876, name: 'Kirk Hammet'}],
  deletedHours: [{hours: 3, id: 5432, name: 'Lucas Moore'}]
};

workedHours = workedHours.filter(h =>
    !response.deletedHours.find(dh => dh.id === h.id) &&  
    !response.updatedHours.find(uh => uh.id === h.id)
).concat(response.updatedHours);

console.log(workedHours);
```

Comment: Though this will be a bit expensive(*extra iterations*), full marks for logic.

Comment: An alternate could be: `var getIds = (x) => x.id; var ids = getIds(res.uh).concat(getIds(res.dh));` ... `.filter((x) => !ids.includes(x.id))`. Multiple `.find` inside `.filter` for a big array can be catastrophic. Try to minimize iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your input Rajesh! this is very helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

This solution iterates the `workedHours` array once, and preserves the original order.

Use [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keyBy) to create a dictionary (POJO) of updated items, and a dictionary of deleted items.

Iterate the `workedHours` with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). If an item is in the updated dictionary, add the updated item to the result. If an item is not in the deleted dictionary, add it to the result.

```js
const workedHours = [{"hours":3,"id":1234,"name":"John Doe"},{"hours":2,"id":5678,"name":"Steve Harris"},{"hours":4,"id":1928,"name":"Richard McNeil"},{"hours":1,"id":9876,"name":"Kirk Hammet"},{"hours":3,"id":5432,"name":"Lucas Moore"}];
const response = {"updatedHours":[{"hours":4,"id":5678,"name":"Steve Harris"},{"hours":2,"id":9876,"name":"Kirk Hammet"}],"deletedHours":[{"hours":3,"id":5432,"name":"Lucas Moore"}]};

const updatedDict = _.keyBy(response.updatedHours, 'id');
const deletedDict = _.keyBy(response.deletedHours, 'id');

const result = workedHours.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(updatedDict[o.id]) r.push(updatedDict[o.id]);
  else if(!deletedDict[o.id]) r.push(o);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach Ori. Your answer helps me alot! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to do it under `n` complexity. I haven't used lodash, but I believe this can be converted to lodash equivalent code.

The idea is:

- Convert the base hours array to a map, keyed by the `id` attribute.
- For each of the deleted hours, delete the entry from the map.
- For each updated our, update the entry in the map.
- Get the array of values from the map using `Object.values()`.

Working example:

```js
const hours = [
  {hours: 3, id: 1234, name: 'John Doe'},
  {hours: 2, id: 5678, name: 'Steve Harris'},
  {hours: 4, id: 1928, name: 'Richard McNeil'},
  {hours: 1, id: 9876, name: 'Kirk Hammet'},
  {hours: 3, id: 5432, name: 'Lucas Moore'},
];

const response = {
  updatedHours: [
    {hours: 4, id: 5678, name: 'Steve Harris'},
    {hours: 2, id: 9876, name: 'Kirk Hammet'},
  ],
  deletedHours: [
    {hours: 3, id: 5432, name: 'Lucas Moore'},
  ]
};

const map = hours.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

response.deletedHours.forEach(hour => {
  delete map[hour.id];
});

response.updatedHours.forEach(hour => {
  map[hour.id] = hour;
});

console.log(Object.values(map));
```

Comment: The point was, when you add a snippet which throws error, it might attract unwanted comments/votes and users will not be able to test it. I understand the code and could not agree more with performance aspect of it.

Comment: Caveat for readers, do check for validity of `map[hour.id] !== undefined`. In real life scenario, it can throw error.

Comment: Thanks for you answer on this. This is very helfull